# Tomahawk for JSF 2.1

Tags: jsf, myfaces, tomahawk

Does "Tomahawk for JSF 2.0" works for JSF 2.1 / MyFaces Core 2.1 ?
If not, a new release "Tomahawk for JSF 2.1" is expected/announced anytime soon ?

If not, will there be any downside using "Tomahawk for JSF 2.0" and JSF 2.0 / MyFaces Core 2.0

I am upgrading from MyFaces 1.2.6 + Facelets 1.1.15-jsf1.2 (using lots of templates)

Thanks very much in advance.

Regards,
Kumar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Tomahawk for JSF 2.0 will work just fine for JSF 2.1. We also use it in production.

JSF 2.1 is not a specification change, but merely a maintenance release. JSF 1.2 -> 2.0 was however a major specification change and that's why JSF 1.x targeted component libraries won't work for JSF 2.x.

Comment: Thanks very much. It is very helpful. Appreciate your kind help.